# ubuntu 12.04 system error/macchanger issue?

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, system, apport

specifics:

Ubuntu 12.04
gateway LT2800 series

1gb ram

Intel GMA 3150

I just started getting a system error. I don't know if it's related to my issue with macchanger. But this is the issue I'm most concerned with.

I have written a short bash script to change my mac address.

It looks about like this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down &&
macchanger -A wlan0 &&
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

I always disable networking using the network manager before I execute the script. It's located in my home folder. I run the script like this:

```
sudo /scripts/changemac
```

The terminal prints this after execution:

```
Permanent MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)

Current   MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)

New       MAC: 00:e0:62:f0:6c:56 (Host Engineering)
```

ifconfig will affirm to me that my mac address has changed.

Then when I connect to an access point I get an error. When I run ifconfig afterwards it shows my original mac address.

The error is `/usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py`

and

Apport has detected a possible GPU hang.  Did your system recently lock up and/or require a hard reboot?

I would prefer to avoid a complete re-install.

Thanks. Let me know what other information you might need to help me this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this problem. I'm going to wait a few days and make sure.

My script broke network manager I think. I added the command:

```
restart network-manager
```

Now when I connect, the Mac address stays changed.

I think I prefer to use wicd instead though.

The completed script if anyone wants to use it :

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down &&
sudo macchanger -A wlan0 &&
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up &&
sudo restart network-manager
```